# Read variable from app.js in index.html file in a website Bluemix application

Tags: javascript, ibm-cloud, iot, watson-iot

I'm developing a web application to control a smart home device. I'm designing it using the Bluemix IoT Platform, but I'm having some issues that I cannot solve.

I'm reading a variable `(currentRelay1)` in my `app.js` file, that is read directly from the IoT device.

```
var Client = require('ibmiotf');

var appClientConfig = {
    "org" : "rmpr4l",
    "id" : "dineriot",
    "domain": "internetofthings.ibmcloud.com",
    "auth-key" : "a-rmps4l-0uegqtl8mec",
    "auth-token" : "V8vB!?R3yES7dc@vtj"
};

var appClient = new Client.IotfApplication(appClientConfig);

appClient.connect();

appClient.on("connect", function () {

    appClient.subscribeToDeviceEvents();

});
appClient.on("deviceEvent", function (deviceType, deviceId, eventType, format, payload) {

    console.log("Device Event from :: "+deviceType+" : "+deviceId+" of event "+eventType+" with payload : "+payload);

    var json = JSON.parse(payload);
    currentRelay1 = json["C1"] * 1000;
    currentRelay2 = json["C2"] * 1000;

});
```

Now, I want to share this variable to use it in a `index.html` file to plot a chart.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Since this is your server side code you will need to send this data to your page. Or the page to request it from the server. Unfortunately this is a very big topic :)

You can setup a server that will respond with this like so:

server.js // "data" is your variable

```
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });
    res.write("data: " + data + '\n\n');
    res.end();
}).listen(8000);
```

client.js //included into your .html file

```
<script>
    function handler(e){
        if (e.target.readyState == 4 && e.target.status == 200) {
            //use "e.target.data" here
        }
    }

    var r = new XMLHttpRequest();
    r.open('GET', 'http://localhost:8000');
    r.addEventListener(readystatechange, handler);
    r.send();
</script>
```

Further reading:
https://nodejs.org/api/http.html
https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_http.asp